# Finding the bounds of a series in terms of an integral and using this to compute the limit of the series

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, limits, power-series, upper-lower-bounds

If you consider the sum $s_n = n / n^2 + n/ (n^2 + 1) + ... + n / (n^2 + (n - 1)^2)$
and give an upper and a lower estimate for s$_n$ in terms of the integral from 0 to n $I_n = ∫ n/(n^2 + x^2))dx$. How can you use this to compute the limit of $s_n$ as $n → ∞$?

This is what I’ve tried so far to solve this question:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqQE0.jpg

But as you can see I got stuck. Any feedback, help or tips would be very much appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

$\frac n {n^{2}+(j+1)^{2}} \leq \int_j^{j+1} \frac n {n^{2}+x^{2}}dx \leq \frac n {n^{2}+j^{2}}$. Summing from $j=1$ to $j=n-1$ we find that $s_n-\frac  1 {2n} \leq \int_1^{n} \frac n {n^{2}+x^{2}} \leq s_n$. Also $\int_j^{j+1} \frac n {n^{2}+x^{2}}dx=\arctan (\frac  x n) |_1^{n}$ from which you can see that $s_n \to \arctan 1=\frac {\pi} 4$.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot! My integral actually has to go from 0 to n, but this could just be solved by picked j = 0 and j = n-1, right? I'm just struggling with the part where you say that the first summation is the same as $s_n - 1/2n$ < ... I tried writing it out but I just don't see it... Also, I'm still struggling a bit with what exactly we're doing now. Is $s_n - 1/2n$ the lowerbound  and $s_n$ the upperbound? How can the partial sum itself be the upperbound? I don't really understand.

Comment: When you sum you will get the same terms as in $s_n$ except that the first term $\frac n {n^{2}}$ would be missing and there will be an extra term $\frac n {n^{2}+n^{2}}$.  @anonymousmath

Comment: Oh, that was actually pretty obvious, sorry hahah.But for the interpretation, should you rewrite it so s_n comes in the middle of the equation and then what's on the left and right are the lower- and upperbound?